# Split Numbered String

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
1. the main cause of [explosions].
2. any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon after, you explode for no reason.
3. what scientists do to make stuff explode.
4. when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].
2. Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day].
3. slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].
4. A means of evaluating another person's character through a series of [unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves to define which people are desirable company and which should not be associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a test-failer is a bad person.
Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the test!"
Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person's existence.
5. It is terrible.
```

I'd like to split this string based on the \n, BUT, in the case of something like number 4, only on the last \n character. I want to capture everything between the 1st digit and the next digit as individual strings in the resulting list.

EDIT WITH DESIRED OUTPUT LIST

```
['1. the main cause of [explosions].\r', 
'2. any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon after, you explode for no reason.\r', 
'3. what scientists do to make stuff explode.\r', 
'4. when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].', 
'2. Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day]. ', 
'3. slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].', 
"4. A means of evaluating another person's character through a series of [unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves to define which people are desirable company and which should not be associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a test-failer is a bad person. Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the test!" Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person\'s existence.\r”, 
'5. To [check] if something coresponds the promised result [or what] [effect] does it have at all.', '6. A [process] for [testing] [things]',
'7. What you [take in] school to [determine] if you pass or [fail] in life.', 
'8. The word all students fear.', "A piece of paper that might [screw up] someones life if they don't write anything on it.", 'Something that makes most students wish to die on the weeks before they go into the room and take the test.', 'Something that makes most students have [teamwork] spirit.', 'A paper that teachers love to surprise, [scare] and threat their students with.', 
'9. A [process] of finding out whether something works or not.\r', 
"2. An [oral] or written [exam] to find out one's ability in one or more subjects.", 
'10. To try someone or [go up] against another by [getting on] ones nerves or [manhood].', 
'']
```

Notice that the string starting with "4." is one continuous string from 4. all the way to "person\'s existence.\r", rather than being split by the \n after "is a bad person" and ""You pass the test!""

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you want to reach?

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: Try this regex: `re.findall('(\d+\..*\n?)',s)`

Comment: @PeterWood I'm looking for a Python answer.

Comment: @MPJ567 See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @QuangHoang that doesn't get the extra lines for the second `4.`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Peter is correct, your recommendation gets me so very close, but it does not get the extra lines for 4. 

Peter, I will attempt to edit appropriately, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
data = '''1. the main cause of [explosions].
2. any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon after, you explode for no reason.
3. what scientists do to make stuff explode.
4. when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].
2. Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day].
3. slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].
4. A means of evaluating another person's character through a series of [unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves to define which people are desirable company and which should not be associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a test-failer is a bad person.
Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the test!"
Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person's existence.
5. It is terrible.'''

new_list = []
final_sentence = ""

for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.strip()[0].isdigit():
        if final_sentence:
            new_list.append(final_sentence)
        final_sentence  = line
    else:
        final_sentence +=' '+line

new_list.append(final_sentence)
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['1. the main cause of [explosions].', 
'2. any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon after, you explode for no reason.', 
'3. what scientists do to make stuff explode.', 
'4. when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].', 
'2. Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day].', 
'3. slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].', 
'4. A means of evaluating another person\'s character through a series of [unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves to define which people are desirable company and which should not be associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a test-failer is a bad person. Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the test!" Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person\'s existence.',
'5. It is terrible.']
```

**Validation:**

```
>>> len(new_list)
8
```

**Explanation:**

First, looping over each line using `.split('\n')`.

Second, Checking whether the first element is digit or not.

Third, I have declared a empty list and string, which is used to make our final sentence and collect each final_sentence into a list.

1. when `.isdigit()` is True, we need to assign to final_sentence.
2. when `.isdigit()` is False, we need to append string to
   final_sentence.

   - Now, we need to append our final_sentence to `new_list`. Which is the
     right place to do that? (Tricky part)
   - Our `final_sentence` was completely build when it again assign a new
     string i.e., in `.isdigit()` is True. There we are    checking,
     weather the `final_sentence` have data or not. If yes,    append to
     our `new_list`.

Comment: looks like a great solution, I was hoping you might be able to explain it further, I can't quite figure out why it works, and I'd love to know so I can better apply it in the future. 

I get that it splits on the newline character, then checks if first character is a digit, and then I'm lost. In particular I cannot figure out what "if t:" is doing.

Comment: @MPJ567 Added explanation. As you are interested in learning, I left explanation part for `new_list.append(final_sentence)`, which is used outside `for-loop` for you. I guess you have already figured it out. Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.split`

**Ex:**

```
data = """1. the main cause of [explosions].
2. any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon after, you explode for no reason.
3. what scientists do to make stuff explode.
4. when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].
2. Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day].
3. slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].
4. A means of evaluating another person's character through a series of [unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves to define which people are desirable company and which should not be associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a test-failer is a bad person.
Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the test!"
Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person's existence.
5. It is terrible."""

data =re.split(r"(\d+)\.", data)[1:]

result = [n+m for n,m in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['1 the main cause of [explosions].\n',
 '2 any thing [dreaded] that your "teachers" say is "good" for you. soon '
 'after, you explode for no reason.\n',
 '3 what scientists do to make stuff explode.\n',
 '4 when a sheet of paper explodes into [flames].\n',
 '2 Everything that is [put in] [front] of you during any given [day].\n',
 '3 slang for [testosterone]..[steroid] [hormones].\n',
 "4 A means of evaluating another person's character through a series of "
 '[unannounced], [inconspicuous] examinations. Developed by Eddie, it serves '
 'to define which people are desirable company and which should not be '
 'associated with. As a general rule, a test-passer is a good person while a '
 'test-failer is a bad person.\n'
 'Passing the test results in the joyous [proclamation] that "You pass the '
 'test!"\n'
 'Failure of a test is announced simply by saying "You failed the test." This '
 "phrase is often used to show general disdain for a person's existence.\n",
 '5 It is terrible.']
```

Comment: Your answer was very close, and I'm enjoying learning about re.split and zip, but I've marked Shaik's as the answer since it maintains the period after the digit.

Comment: Just an FYI, If you need the period after the digit use `(\d+\.)` --> ex: `data = re.split(r"(\d+\.)", data)[1:]`